# All refreshes to be hard refreshes

Tags: javascript

I am working on a legacy webpage that the layout breaks in Chrome only when a user refreshes. So, I noticed that if I hold down shift+refresh it load the UI correctly the next time the user refreshes. This is a quick bug that do not want to spend too much time on. This is what I have so far:

```
 var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

 if( is_chrome && document.refresh.visited.value == "" ){
   document.refresh.visited.value = "1";
 }
 else{
  location.reload(true);
 }
```

I also have a hidden input with a value="" at the top of the page. I just want to be able to do a hard refresh every time they come to this page the second time and every time thereafter.

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem, but I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking.

Comment: So what is you problem now? Does location.reload(true) do what you expect?

Comment: It is a caching issue sorry if I wasn't clear. The u/i goes back to normal after shift+f5. Location.reload(true) in this case keeps reloading over and over.

Comment: Your code does unlimited reloads for Internet Explorers.. That's a nice idea :)

Comment: Seems very strange to me to try solving this at the JavaScript level. Can you serve all assets that need to be refreshed with the appropriate expire headers?

Comment: Very odd issue that is only related to Chrome 26 on windows and not Chrome 25 on Ubuntu. To top it all off its inside of iframes. The expire headers did not solve the prob unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this function:

```
function getParameter(paramName) {
  var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
      i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

  for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
    val = params[i].split("=");
    if (val[0] == paramName) {
      return unescape(val[1]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

and then use:

window.location = 'yourPage.html?reloadMe=true';

So your code would be:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
var reload = true;
if(getParameter("reloadMe")=="true"){
    reload = false;
}

if( is_chrome && reload){
    window.location = 'yourPage.html?reloadMe=true';
}
```

I don't know if this will help with your cache issue but it will stop page from reloading over and over again.

Comment: This code works on a blank slate page. But, my issue somehow seems to be with the focus on the iframe on the right hand side which causes some css classes not to show up correctly on refresh. Helpful solution. I'll keep digging.